# What kind of javascript framework is used by this page?

Tags: javascript

I came across the Optimizely web site and noticed the UI is very professional. I would like to know what framework technology could produce such a high quality (besides of the developer's high quality work and commitment of course).

So I looked into the code by pressing F12. The code quality and structure was equally impressive just as the UX. Unfortunately (surely it's my inexperience) I have no idea what kind of code/framework it could be...

It seems it is an extensive framework for both data content binding, and event binding.

I've examined also what .js scripts are referred, however found nothing familiar.

Unfortunately the page is only accessible for registered users, although it would be the best to give a link here it would be useless. Instead here is some code exhibit:

```
<form action="#" class="input-group" data-bind="css: { focused: isPathFocused() }, submit: function(){$root.reload(true);}">
   <label for="path">Path:</label>
   <span class="prefix" data-bind="text: domain">https://www.google.com</span>
   <input type="text" id="path" name="path" data-bind="hasfocus: isPathFocused, value: path">
   <button type="submit" id="load-page-button">Load</button>
</form>
<button id="preview-toggle" class="preview-toggle-button" data-bind="attr: { title: viewState.isCollapsed() ? 'Expand preview pane' : 'Collapse preview pane' },
   click: $root.viewState.collapseOnClick,
   css: { collapsed: viewState.isCollapsed },
   text: viewState.isCollapsed() ? 'Expand' : 'Collapse'" title="Collapse preview pane">Collapse</button>
<button id="preview-toggle-close" class="preview-toggle-button" data-bind="click: $root.viewState.closeOnClick" title="Close preview pane">Close</button>
```

Here is the head element:

```
<head>
  <script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="//cdn3.optimizely.com/js/geo2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://vis.optimizely.com/api/targetingEmbed/5935064/3375340400/oeu1445896359844r0.5723679552320391"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="//cdn3.optimizely.com/js/geo2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://optimizely.skymosity.com/sp.js?callback=optimizely_skymosity"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Optimizely Preview</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/master-2185.388478123618610666/dist/css/preview.css">
  <script src="/master-2185.388478123618610666/dist/js/preview2.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.optimizely.com/js/5935064.js"></script>
  <script src="https://odds.optimizely.com/js/geo2.js?c__mkto_trk=id%3A361-GER-922%26token%3A_mch-optimizely.com-1445896362127-52041&amp;project=5935064" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://vis.optimizely.com/api/targetingEmbed/5935064/3375340400/oeu1445896359844r0.5723679552320391" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <iframe src="https://5935064.cdn.optimizely.com/client_storage/5935064.html"></iframe>
</head>
```

Comment: I guess its using Knockout.js

Comment: Well I heard but never used neither angular neither knockout. But I have to say I _did_ my homework an looked both for 10-15 minutes, with not conclusion if any of the is used by the code under investigation.

Comment: It looks like data binding is done using this... https://www.getlytics.com/

Comment: Also my friend, just a pointer , there are plenty of good frameworks like Angular, Knockout, Reach, Polymer and many more. The real question is which one to choose and why? Everyone has their pros and cons.

Comment: The programming framework has very rarely anything to do with the quality of the UI.

Comment: @Rajesh: Agree that's the real question.That is exactly what I am looking for. _So_ I looked a well working website which has similar functionality, specification and UX what I am going to implement and taking it as a proof of concept, and now trying to find out what technologies it is using. Trying to find a direction by working sample

Comment: @Juhana: I mentioned the code quality too. Also consider: Who has the wish to make (implement) quality in one area, supposedly she/he has a general attitude for do that in other areas too.

Comment: I'd suggest, you research on frameworks. Compare whose pros suits your application and whose cons affect you least. Also a fully working web application takes time to build and hence it may not have the latest framework, where certain issues might have been solved.

Comment: "*…the UI is very professional*" by what criteria? Certainly not any that include accessibility.

Comment: @Rajesh: Again, that is what I am doing. I know that a "fully working web application takes time to build".

Comment: @RobG: By most of criteria I am intending to use.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) to me.

Sample Knockout for comparison (taken from the official tutorials):

```
<h3>Tasks</h3>

<form data-bind="submit: addTask">
    Add task: <input data-bind="value: newTaskText" placeholder="What needs to be done?" />
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>

<ul data-bind="foreach: tasks, visible: tasks().length > 0">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isDone" />
        <input data-bind="value: title, disable: isDone" />
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeTask">Delete</a>
    </li> 
</ul>

You have <b data-bind="text: incompleteTasks().length">&nbsp;</b> incomplete task(s)
<span data-bind="visible: incompleteTasks().length == 0"> - it's beer time!</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, although your sample is convincing, how it is possible I can not find the traces of the knockout script element in the page?

Comment: In the head sample you posted, there's a reference to an iFrame. Did you check inside that for further script references?

Comment: Yes I reviewed that. Only one inline and obfuscated script element is inside. Btw (it could be my limited knowledge) I do not know how ti utilize a script in a _usual_ _way_ which is within an iframe. I know there is possible to communicate between frames, but that's an other topic. I am sure the iframe does some dirty trick, but it seems to be unrelated with the framework and data binding what the page is using. It sounds overcomplicated to utilize knockout with this way instead simple referring it in a normal script tag.

Comment: Without being able to see the page in question or it's full source, I can't tell what the iframe does. I was making a guess that perhaps the actual content for the page was within that iframe, but I assume I was wrong.

Guessing the application based on the limited urls above, it's a corporate site looking to make money from businesses by doing `something`.. it wouldn't surprise me if they're being tricky with their referenced scripts based on requesting urls / method of access / etc.. making it trickier to pick apart their JS..